# Media queries do not work for more than one query

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design, media-queries

Firefox Developer edition in its Responsive Web Design has 7 screen size pairs and of those 11 different sizes; several media queries are necessary to cover the sizes listed.

I created a stylesheet for the format for the largest size. from there, I created a separate stylesheet for the 320px to 640px ranges screen sizes. The html page has the link to the styles sheet:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and

```html
<link 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  type="text/css" 
  href="styles/320_home.css"
  type="text/css"
  media="screen and (max-width: 635px)" 
/>
```

The stylesheet has this format:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  -- css statements --
}
```

When the page is opened in Firefox and tested in its RWD environment, it works perfectly.

I created a second separate stylesheet for the next size range using the exact same query format:
on the html page:

```html
<link 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  type="text/css" 
  href="styles/768_home.css"
  media= "screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1200px) 
/>
```

and on the separate stylesheet

```css
@media screen and  (width:768px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  -- css statements --
}
```

could not change a thing on the web page.

I put the the 320px to 640px ranges on the main style sheet underneath all of the original css: it worked perfectly.

Did the same thing with the second size range: again, could not change a thing on the web page.

Now, I have viewed the other media query questions. I have done exactly as recommended; yet, I can not get the web page to respond to more than one media query.
As solutions?

Addendum:

This is an inner page; multiple separate style sheets worked on the landing page which went through major changes as it went from the smallest width (320px) to the final (1366px). This is no longer a question of multiple query sheets vs a god awful amount of embedded queries in the main style sheet. It is an issue of why won't the by the book code be consistently effective.

Comment: Unless you have a _massive_ amount of differing styles for the different sizes, you should rather put your default styles and all MQs into one stylesheet, instead of embedding several stylesheets with the media attribute on the link element.

Comment: What happens at exactly 768px wide?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have specified the CSS to only work when the screen is 768 pixels wide:

```
@media screen and  (width:768px) and (max-width:1200px){
  //CSS Here
}
```

What I think you are looking for is for the *minimum width* to be 768 pixels, for which you would need this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1200px){
  //CSS Here
}
```

That works on screen between 768 and 1200 pixels wide.

Comment: I've done it both ways; I've formatted it your way and I have formatted it where the max-width precedes the min-width.
I've done everything except sacrifice the cat to the fickle gods of css.